# How can i autogenerate class diagrams and sequence diagrams?

Tags: php

Can anybody tell me how can i autogenerate class diagrams and sequence diagrams from my classes in php? I am using CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is a tool for that.

[PHP_UML](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML/)